# How to create a shell script to display all PID started by a program?

Tags: scripts

How to create a shell script to display all PID of processes started by a program, each on a new line. The script should accept the path to the program as a parameter like: ./displaypid.sh {path_to_the_program}

This is what I've wrote in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pidof $1
```

but i think it isn't enough.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu "pidof" will display all processes ?

Answer (score 2):

```
pidof PROGRAM_NAME
```

it's enourh.

From `man pidof`:

> ```
> Pidof finds the process id's (pids) of the named  programs.  It  prints 
> those id's on the standard output.
> ```

Additionally, you can use:

```
pgrep PROGRAM_NAME
```

or:

```
ps ax | grep PROGRAM_NAME | grep -v grep | cut -d' ' -f2
```